# What happens when a ritual summoned Eidolon is hit with dispel magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, eidolon

What happens when an Eidolon who has been summoned using the minute ritual? The ritual doesnt say if its SU/Ex/SLA or anything, so it might be fine or it might act like the spell version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If the eidolon is summoned using the normal ritual, then [*Dispel Magic*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) will not banish them.

The summoner's [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Eidolon) class feature says explicitly that

> The eidolon cannot be sent back to its home plane by means of *dispel magic*, but spells such as *dismissal* and *banishment* work normally.

If hit by *Dispel Magic*, then act as if *Dispel Magic* had been cast on any other creature. This may dispel any spell effects currently on the eidolon.

But there is one exception: If the eidolon is summoned using the [*Summon Eidolon*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-eidolon/) spell, then *Dispel Magic* will actually banish them.

> While summoned in this way, your eidolon cannot touch any creature warded by protection from evil or a similar effect and your eidolon can be sent back to its home plane by dispel magic.

Comment: I had missed that (or forgotten) in the description, thank you